# Как здесь подсчитать количество повторных значений

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
rom collections import deque

q = deque([2, 7, 'python', "django", 'django', 7, 4, 6, 'PyQt5', 6, 'Numpy', 'Pandas', 6])
```

Comment: Может все-таки речь о `collections.Counter`, а не о `collections.deque`?

Answer (score 0):

```
print(len(q) - len(set([ a for a in q ])))

4
```